# Return message after mention

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to code a game for a Discord bot and I have a little problem with this code:

```
(async function() {
  if (command == "rps") {
    message.channel.send("**Please mention a user you want to play with.**");

    var member = message.mentions.members.first()
    if (!member) return; {
      const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(0xffffff)
        .setFooter('Please look in DMs')
        .setDescription(args.join(' '))
        .setTitle(`<@> **Do you accept** <@>**'s game?**`);
      let msg = await message.channel.send(embed);
      await msg.react('✅');
      await msg.react('❎');
    }
  }
})();
```

I want to EmbedMessage return after mention member. Like this:
User: `rps`
Bot: `Please mention a user`
User: `mention user`
Bot: `embed`

Comment: What exactly isn't working in your code, any errors in console? After the if statement you return and create a new scope.. is that intended?

Comment: What's the issue? What isn't working? What exactly do you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages):

```
(async function() {
  if (command == "rps") {
    message.channel.send("**Please mention a user you want to play with.**");

    let filter = msg => {
      if (msg.author.id != message.author.id) return false; // the message has to be from the original author
      if (msg.mentions.members.size == 0) { // it needs at least a mention
        msg.reply("Your message has no mentions.");
        return false;
      }
      return msg.mentions.members.first().id != msg.author.id; // the mention should not be the author itself
    };
    let collected = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      maxMatches: 1,
      time: 60000
    });

    // if there are no matches (aka they didn't reply)
    if (collected.size == 0) return message.edit("Command canceled.");
    // otherwise get the member
    let member = collected.first().mentions.members.first();

    const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setColor(0xffffff)
      .setFooter('Please look in DMs')
      .setDescription(args.join(' '))
      .setTitle(`<@> **Do you accept** <@>**'s game?**`);
    let msg = await message.channel.send({
      embed
    });
    await msg.react('✅');
    await msg.react('❎');
  }
})();
```